# Iterate through NS array of obs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray

I need to take this data structure, an nsmutablearray, and iterate through each index and print each field into a textfield. every "forward" button increments the data ahead and "backwards" goes back. I am having a really hard time getting this to work properly, does anyone know what im doing wrong. Keep in mind, the object held in the array, called info_holder, is an object that holds 3 strings and one counter:

```
#import "ZDViewController.h"

@implementation ZDViewController
@synthesize password;
@synthesize count;
@synthesize web;
@synthesize username;
@synthesize header;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    info_holder *set1 = [[info_holder alloc] init];
    info_holder *set2 = [[info_holder alloc] init];
    info_holder *set3 = [[info_holder alloc] init];
    info_holder *set4 = [[info_holder alloc] init];
    info_holder *set5 = [[info_holder alloc] init];
    [set1 SetUser: @"info1"]; //temporary information until big is fixed
    [set1 SetPass: @"info2"];
    [set1 SetKey: @"webinfo1"];
    [set1 SetCount: 0];
    [set2 SetUser: @"info3"];
    [set2 SetPass: @"info4"];
    [set2 SetKey: @"webinfo2"];
    [set2 SetCount: 0];
    [set3 SetUser: @"info5"];
    [set3 SetPass: @"info6"];
    [set3 SetKey: @"webinfo3"];
    [set3 SetCount: 0];
    [set4 SetUser: @"info7"];
    [set4 SetPass: @"info8"];
    [set4 SetKey: @"webinfo4"];
    [set4 SetCount: 0];
    [set5 SetUser: @"info9"];
    [set5 SetPass: @"info10"];
    [set5 SetKey: @"Webinfo5"];
    [set5 SetCount: 0];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setHeader:nil];
    [self setWeb:nil];
    [self setPassword:nil];
    [self setCount:nil];
    [self setUsername:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)increment:(id)sender {
    if(username.text==@"test")
        username.text=@"test2";
    else
        username.text=@"test";
    //this should print a new username NSSTRING, wedsite NSTRING, password NSTRING and INEGER counter, heald in the info_holder object, incremented per click backwards 
}

- (IBAction)decrement:(id)sender {

}
- (IBAction)Inc:(id)sender {

}
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [web resignFirstResponder];
    [username resignFirstResponder];
    [count resignFirstResponder];
    [password resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

and my main is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ZDAppDelegate.h"
#import "info_holder.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ZDAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: You never, ever need to change your main.m at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)forwards:(id)sender {
    //this should print a new username NSSTRING, wedsite NSTRING, password NSTRING and INEGER counter, heald in the info_holder object, incremented per click forward
for(int i=0;i<your_array.count;i++){
    username.text=[your_array objectAtIndex:i];
    password.text=[your_array objectAtIndex:i];
    key.text.text=[your_array objectAtIndex:i];


}
}
```

**Note-1:** I assume your texrfield names as `username`, `password` and `key`

**Note-2**: Your question is too long an i think no one will read so many code to find your matter. Just share what you need .

Comment: thats the exact issue, its giving me an error saying your_array, which is called logins in my case, is not declared but I did declare it a few lines up. plus, the object at index i of the array will have an object info_holder, and info_holder has a 3 textfields (username, password and key) and one integer (counter) the issue is properly referencing each string within the object within the array

Comment: Which line in your code example above are you getting the error logins is not declared? Because I see you declaring logins in your `viewDidLoad` method. You cannot access logins from anywhere except that method. If you are trying to access logins from the forwards: method, you need to make logins a property of the class.

Comment: thats exactly what I need help with. but how do I do that. I am a beginner and could really use some help

Comment: See my amended answer and then read Apples docs on programming Objective-C

Comment: @AironZagarella: I make all of tree assingment and than increment the i(mean, index in your case). As far as i understood from your question this is true. And you need to access the variables over properties in a class(abd by delegating from different class in the project).(@dbajkovic too has pointed a little). Apple docs are good but CS193p video lectures are great to me. Just google that and watch over iTunes

Answer (score 1):

First, Class names should start in Caps and method names should start in lower case.

Second, your setters in info_holder class (which should be InfoHolder) have potential issues.

an example setter should look like:

```
 - (void)setUser:(NSString *)username
{    
    [username retain];
    [uname release];
    uname=username;     
}
```

You didn't state what's not working, but one problem is that you're not retaining those strings.

**BASED ON COMMENTS**
You need to declare logins a property.

in `ZDViewController.h`

```
@interface ZDViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *logins;
```

Then in `ZDViewController.m`

```
@implementation ZDViewController

@synthesize logins;
.
.
.

- (void)viewDidLoad {
logins = [NSMutableArray array];
.
.
.
}
```

Then you can access self.logins from anywhere in your class

Comment: it didn't but it helped a lot. Im still having trouble with getting each string from within the object within the array. Thanks, i will wait a little longer then check a final answer

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what's not working. And you probably need to spend more time learning Objective-C instead of coming here expecting people to program your solutions for you.

Comment: It's clear you don't understand Objective-C Classes. You will continually be lost if you don't spend a little time learning the basics.

Answer (score 0):

did you stored your info_holder objects into the NSMutableArray instance, If so then you can access the element(info holder instances in your case) of mutable array by either one of the below method,
`for(ClassName *tmp in _arrayName){ tmp.property1;tmp.property2;..... }`
or if you want it as index specific
 `for(int index=0;index<[_arrayName count];index++){  ClassName *tmp = [_arrayName objectAtIndex:index];tmp.property1;tmp.property2;.....}`
. I exactly can't understand your problem but from your writings i guess thee above can be the solution. If not let me know your question , if this certainly helped you then accept the answer. 
**Note:** As @dbrajkovic suggest , always follow the naming convention in your programs, that give more flexible readability.